# What's the exact meaning of uint8_t in TinyOS?

Tags: sensors, tinyos, nesc

everyone! I'm trying to become familiar with TinyOS.
I'd like to know the difference between uint8_t and uint16_t.

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: They seem to be unsigned 8 bit integer and unsigned 16 bit integers. Check out this useful page from Microsoft for explanations of those types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of thoroughness:

Data types come in many shapes and sizes. The two you are referring to are of types `unsigned 8 bit integer` and `unsigned 16 bit integer`.

An integer is a whole number that can be positive or negative; however, in the case of types an unsigned integer can only be positive as it does not designate space for a sign (i.e. a negative sign). 8 bit and 16 bit refer to the amount of space the integer takes up in memory. An `unsigned 8 bit integer`'s values can be 0 - 255 while an unsigned 16 bit integer can hold values from 0 - 65,535 (Side note: If you are familiar with networking you may notice that 65,535 is the largest port number possible. This is due to the fact a port number is an `unsigned 16 bit integer`.)

Hope this helps.